# TFS in Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I used before free TFS from Visual Studio Online. I worked fine, I added some projects to TFS and did check-in and check-out without problem. But now it just stop working. When I try to check-in new projects, I get the following error:

> The following issues were encountered during check in: TF10169:
>   Unsupported pending change attempted on team project folder $/Code. 
>   Use the Project Creation Wizard in Team Explorer to create a project
>   or the Team Project deletion tool to delete one.

What is Project Creation Wizard? How I can run it? And what is happened with my account? I see the message:

> Your account is an Early Adopter account. In 31 days your account will
>   revert to a standard account.

Maybe that's why it's not working anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create or delete folders at the top-level of the source tree.  (Eg, `$/Code`).

The top level of the source tree is reserved for Team Projects, which must be created and deleting specially.  If you want to delete `$/Code`, you will need to undo your pending change that deletes it and instead delete it using the Project Creation Wizard or the [TfsDeleteProject command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181482.aspx).

Comment: Okay, I undo pending changes, then added Solution again to source control, then trying to check-in and get the same error. I don't want to delete any folders, I just want to save my code to TFS. What I do wrong?

Comment: Where is Project Creation Wizard? I don't see it.

Comment: and how I can delete Team Project? I don't think I can use Command-line tools in online TFS.

Comment: reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff357756.aspx
where is administration context for the team project collection? Should I look at Source Control Explorer in VS or on Visual Studio Online?

Comment: You can delete a team project in the web access administration portal.  But if you're just trying to check in some pending changes, you certainly shouldn't need to delete a Team Project?

Comment: I created new Team Project and checked-in files, I need to delete some old projects. Okay, I found administrative panel at last and removed projects.